# A previous git revert is deleting files in a new merge

Tags: git, merge, revert

A colligue of mine merged a feature branch into our main development branch. I did a revert on that commit. Now I want to merge the development branch into the feature branch, but git deletes all the new files in the feature branch.

I guess this is happening because there is a common ancestor, the wrong full commit that got reverted.

How do I merge development into feature branch retaining all the code in the feature branch?

Comment: This is expected, because a revert commits the _removal_ of files, and then when you merge those files will be removed.

Comment: You can merge into the feature branch and after that revert the reverting commit.